# how to set django model field value based on value of other field in the different model

Tags: django, django-admin

I am extremely new to `django`.  I want to add field values based on other field value of other class. How can do this? can I do it with `django` custom actions?
please help

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Teachers(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.teacher_name

class Students(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,related_name="students_teachers")
    student_rollno = models.IntegerField()
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name

class Subjects(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teachers,related_name="subjects_teachers")
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students,related_name="subjects_students")
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name
```

Here, i create three models ('Teachers, Students, Subjects')
In Students class i  use Teachers class as foreign key. 
and in Subjects i use Teachers and Students as foreign key.

In admin section : 
in Subjects section Teachers, and Studetns dropdown is shown.

*Hope its help you :-)*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this below..

```
from App1 import Model1
from App2 import Model2

q1 = Model1.objects.filter(pk=something)

if q1:
    field1 = q1[0].field1
    q2 = Model1.objects.filter(pk=something)
    if field1 =='something':
        if q2:
              q2[0].field2 == 'something'
              q2[0].save()
```

Note:  (pk - primary key)

1. Model1.objects.get(somefield=something) will throw error if there is no results or more than one results
2. Model1.objects.filter(somefield=something) will not throw errors if there is no results

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to do it in django admin custom actions